# NSFetchedResultsController not updating data into UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have the function:

```
- (void)initFetchRequest
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Shindy" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    // Configure the request's entity, and optionally its predicate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"details" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                              initWithFetchRequest:request
                                              managedObjectContext:context
                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                              cacheName:nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }    
}
```

With the following within my `viewDidLoad` method

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]];
document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];
self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;

[self initFetchRequest];
```

And finally, this within my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
Shindy *shindy = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = shindy.details;
```

Data is being inputted from another controller, and when I segue back to this controller, the `UITableViewController` isn't updating.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Use `fetchedResultsController` as `self.fetchedResultsController` everywhere consistently to make sure you are referring to the correct object

Comment: Also, why are you executing `performFetch` twice in `initFetchRequest` method?

Comment: I was trying both. I forgot to delete it before posting this code. I added `self`... still not working :(

Comment: Check that the data you are saving is actually getting saved correctly

Comment: Well, I was using `NSLog` to make sure that the data was getting saved in the other controller where I was inputting the data, but when I segue back to the initial view controller, the same `NSLog` returns `NULL`.

Comment: you should check the way you save and retrieve your data from NSManagedObject. May be you are referring to different copy of NSManagedObject or your data is NOT actually getting saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming back from another View Controller (e.g. with pop in a navigation controller), your `viewDidLoad` is not called. Therefor your data will not be updated. If you want that to happen, you should implement the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and set `fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;`. It will update your table whenever a change occurs. There is a less elegant solution, to call your `initFetchRequest` method from `viewWillAppear` but I would recommend the first solution. Hope this helps!

Comment: I added `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;` in my `viewWillAppear` method... still not working :(

Comment: That's not wat I said. You should add that in your `initFetchRequest` method and implement it like it sais here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html